# Read file and store in array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I would like to read a file and to produce a numbers of arrays depending on how many chains (M,N,O,..) it would have.

Following is a part of a file:

```
SEQRES   1 M  312  ALA ALA ASP PRO LYS LEU LEU LYS ALA ALA ALA GLU ALA
SEQRES   2 M  312  SER TYR ALA PHE ALA LYS GLU VAL ASP TRP ASN ASN GLY
SEQRES   3 M  312  ILE PHE LEU GLN ALA PRO GLY LYS LEU GLN PRO LEU GLU
SEQRES   4 M  312  ALA LEU LYS ALA ILE ASP LYS MET ILE VAL MET GLY ALA
SEQRES   5 M  213  SER PHE ASN ARG ASN

SEQRES   1 N  312  ASP GLU ILE GLY ASP ALA ALA LYS LYS LEU GLY ASP ALA
SEQRES   2 N  312  SER TYR ALA PHE ALA LYS GLU VAL ASP TRP ASN ASN GLY
SEQRES   3 N  312  ILE PHE LEU GLN ALA PRO GLY LYS LEU GLN PRO LEU GLU
SEQRES   4 N  312  ALA LEU LYS ALA ILE ASP LYS MET ILE VAL MET GLY ALA
SEQRES   5 N  312  ALA ALA ASP PRO LYS LEU LEU LYS ALA ALA ALA GLU ALA
SEQRES   6 N  312  VAL THR SER ARG ALA ASP TRP ASP ASN VAL

SEQRES   1 O  312  HIS HIS LYS ALA ILE GLY SER ILE SER GLY PRO ASN GLY
SEQRES   2 O  312  SER TYR ALA PHE ALA LYS GLU VAL ASP TRP ASN ASN GLY
SEQRES   3 O  312  ILE PHE LEU GLN ALA PRO GLY LYS LEU GLN PRO LEU GLU
SEQRES   4 O  312  ALA LEU LYS ALA ILE ASP LYS MET ILE VAL
```

This is my code:

```
my @seq;
my $string="";
my @seqFile;
my $file=<>;
open(FILE, "$file");
while (my $line=<FILE>){
    if ($line =~ /^SEQRES/) {
        chomp $line;
        push @seq, [split (/\s+/, $line)] ;
    }
}
close(FILE);
for my $i (0..$#seq) {
    my $ob =$seq[$i][2];
    if ($seq[$i][2] eq $ob ){
        for (my $j=4;$j<=$#{$seq[$i]};$j++) {
            my $temp= $seq[$i][$j];
            $string .= $temp;
        }
        $ob = $seq[$i][2];
        last;
    }
    push @seqFile, $ob;
    push @seqFile, $string;
    $string = ''; #string needs to be empty to store new lines
}
```

With the above sample: 3 arrays M(:)ALAALAASP:...., N(:)ASPGLU.., O(:)HISHISLYS...

I managed to make all SEQRES in one string, but which is not what I wanted.

Somewhere I need to put a `if(){}` and to check `M <=> N` and `N <=> O` are different. Then save the string and start a string and array. But it keeps accumulating as many times of same string as $#seq. Or if I move the position of one `}` then it does not store anything, Either gives me error messages. How can I do this?

Comment: Could show us the exact output you want?

Comment: `With the above sample: 3 arrays...` So you want the first line with a new letter in the third column (e.g. M,N,O) to have columns 5+ concatenated? And then discard other lines? Or join? We can't read your mind any more than perl can, so you should follow M42's advice and edit your question to include expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I was almost like a zombie and still am. what I expected to have is what goldilocks showed. But can we not use array of arrays? And I would like to know how to store all the items under M and then start storing items under N, and so on, by using the above for loop, please?

Comment: goldilocks did not show any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this program does what you need.

Instead of watching for changes in the value of the third field I have written it so that a blank line or the end of the file marks the end of a chain.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'seq.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

my @seqFile;
my $string;
my $ob;

while (<$fh>) {
  if (/^SEQRES/) {           
    my @data = split;
    $string .= join '', @data[4..$#data];
    $ob = $data[2];
  }
  if (eof($fh) or not /\S/) {
    push @seqFile, $ob, $string;
    $ob = $string = undef;
  }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@seqFile;
```

**output**

```perl
$VAR1 = [
          'M',
          'ALAALAASPPROLYSLEULEULYSALAALAALAGLUALASERTYRALAPHEALALYSGLUVALASPTRPASNASNGLYILEPHELEUGLNALAPROGLYLYSLEUGLNPROLEUGLUALALEULYSALAILEASPLYSMETILEVALMETGLYALASERPHEASNARGASN',
          'N',
          'ASPGLUILEGLYASPALAALALYSLYSLEUGLYASPALASERTYRALAPHEALALYSGLUVALASPTRPASNASNGLYILEPHELEUGLNALAPROGLYLYSLEUGLNPROLEUGLUALALEULYSALAILEASPLYSMETILEVALMETGLYALAALAALAASPPROLYSLEULEULYSALAALAALAGLUALAVALTHRSERARGALAASPTRPASPASNVAL',
          'O',
          'HISHISLYSALAILEGLYSERILESERGLYPROASNGLYSERTYRALAPHEALALYSGLUVALASPTRPASNASNGLYILEPHELEUGLNALAPROGLYLYSLEUGLNPROLEUGLUALALEULYSALAILEASPLYSMETILEVAL'
        ];
```

---

**Edit**

Now that I know the data file has no blank lines to delineate the chains, my original solution won't work.

This alternative checks the sequence number in the second field of the records, and starts a new chain when that number is 1. The accumulated chain must also be saved whenever a new chain starts and also at the end of the file after the read loop exits.

The output from this program is identical to that shown above.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'seq.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

my @seqFile;
my $chain;
my $ob;

while (<$fh>) {

  next unless /^SEQRES/;

  my @data = split;
  if ($data[1] == 1) {
    push @seqFile, $ob, $chain if $chain;
    $ob = $chain = undef;
  }
  $chain .= join '', @data[4..$#data];
  $ob = $data[2];
}

push @seqFile, $ob, $chain if $chain;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@seqFile;
```

Comment: Thank you Borodin. The actual file does not have blank lines. Would you give me some idea how to do in that case please?

Comment: `next if /^\s*$/` right at the start of the `while` loop will skip empty lines.

Comment: @mpe: I have added to my answer to provide a solution for the case where the data doesn't contain blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

Do you not see a problem here?

```
my $ob =$seq[$i][2];
if ($seq[$i][2] ne $ob ){
```

This is analogous to:

```
my $x = "this";
if ($x ne "this) {
```

How could the `if` condition ever be true?

A better approach would be to use a hash of arrays, keyed on M, N, or O, (what you are setting $ob to):

```
open (my $fh, '<', $file);   # using global globs like FILE is depreciated
my %hash_of_arrays;
while (<$fh>) {
    my @data = split;
    push @{$hash_of_arrays{$data[2]}}, join('', (@data)[4..$#data]);
}
```

Pretty sure that is close to what you are trying to do; the 2nd arg to `push` uses an *array slice*.

Note that if `@{$hash{$data[2]}}` does not exist yet, it will be created via *autovivification*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification

Comment: There is no need to put `$file` within double quotes.

Comment: Hmm, must have been hypnotized while copying from the original -- corrected.

Comment: You do not need to set the hash value to an empty array before pushing data to it. Perl's autovivification handles that.

Comment: @goldilocks: What TLP means is that you can write `push @{$h{x}}, 42` without first saying `$h{x} = [] unless exists $h{x}` as your code does.

Comment: Eek, forgot the `@{}` when testing the premise.  Did not know about this, but I will edit the post in that light. :)

Comment: Thank you everyone.  That is what I expected, thank you, goldilocks. Can we not use array of arrays ? I have changed if ().